# Questions about ordering of reals and irrationals

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Three problems from G.Rosenstein "Linear orderings" (from the end of Chapter 2 and beginning of Chapter 4):

1) Is there a nondecreasing function from irrationals onto reals?

2) Is there a nondecreasing function from reals onto irrationals?

3) Is there an increasing function from reals into irrationals? (In other words, are reals a subordering of irrationals?)

Any hints would be appreciated.

(Please tag the question set-theory order-theory)

Comment: And maybe there should be a rule that homework should be tagged as such? They have it on StackOverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: Sorry, a better link is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: It's not homework; I'm reading that book recreationally and these are only problems in these chapters I'm stuck on. I can wait longer for an answer. Otherwise I agree that homework should be tagged.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked you directly if it's homework or not...

Comment: Perhaps we should have a tag instead for "exercise"s or "book-problem"s.

Comment: Since we have precedence for the [exercise] tag (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136), I've used that.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about usefulness of the tag "exercise" -- a problem in Hartshorne is quite different from 8 grade, right?

Comment: @ilya: wouldn't a [homework] tag be even worse? Anyway, no 8th grade problems here please.

Comment: Yeah, but if a tag is too narrow it is useless. I think that "exercise in a graduate level text" is about the right level of specificity, and I am fine with calling it "exercise".

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple proof of (3), without continued fractions.

For any real number x, let f(x) be the real obtained by interleaving the binary digits of x with the binary digits of pi, a fixed irrational number. This is clearly order-preserving, and f(x) is irrational since the digits will not repeat. QED

Comment: Minor nit-pick: One has to choose a 2-adic expansion of every $x$ to do this, for example the (uniquely determined) one that has infinitely many ones. It matters because the digit sequences 100000... and 0111111... will be mapped to different irrationals even though they represent the same rational number.

Comment: Yes; so just use your favorite representation (say, the one without tailing $1$s), and there is no problem.

Answer (score 12):

(3) This is only a minute variant on Ilya's answer, but I think it looks a bit more perspicuous in continued fractions.
In fact, there's a *negative continued fraction* expansion that Richard Guy told me about which have a nicer ordering than standard regular cfs.  Every real is uniquely representable as an infinite continued fraction
$x=a_{0}-1/\left(a_{1}-1/\left(a_{2}-1/\left(\ldots\right)\right)\right)$ with all $a_{n}$ in $\mathbb {Z}$ and $a_{n}\ge 2$ for $i\ge 1$.  $x$ is rational iff the all $a_{n}$ are $2$ from some point on.  And the negative continued fractions have the lexicographic order: $x\gt x^{\prime}$ iff $a_{i}\gt a^{\prime}_{i}$ for the first $i$ for which $a_{i}$ and $a^{\prime}_{i}$ differ.

So just map $x$ to $\left(a_{0}+1\right)-1/\left(\left(a_{1}+1\right)-1/\left(\left(a_{2}+1\right)-1/\left(\ldots\right)\right)\right)$.

Comment: This answer is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

1) modify [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) so that all it's growth points are irrational. Then you have a mapping from an interval of irrational numbers to an interval of reals. Then extend to the whole range of numbers.

2) consider a sequence i[n] of irrationals that converges to a rational number. Then if for each member you take the inf of reals that map into it, and consider the limit L of those (it's a bounded sequence so there's a limit), then f(L) is irrational and greater than f(i[n]) for all n. It cannot be rational, so there would be a gap, but since it's an onto mapping there can't be any gaps.

3) if such embedding existed, irrationals and reals would be \infty-equivalent (think infinitely long [Ehrenfeucht–Fraïssé game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game)). But they are not. I think. (well, it's been shown that such embedding is actually possible, so my assumption was incorrect)

Comment: (3) Are you sure you're right? The map will be into, not onto.

Comment: Also, what's the problem with links? Is it because they need to be escaped like in tip 7 of http://mathoverflow.net/tips?

Comment: Two /infty-equivalent structures don't have to be isomorphic if their cardinality is uncountable. But no, I'm not sure if I'm right about this one. 

Comment: And the problem with links is that I have 1 reputation so this site thinks I'm a spammer. Great way to attract new users.

Comment: I added your links.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about the rep restriction. Actually, once there are many people here, you'll be getting a high rep very fast. Here's +10 for you :) but please remove the (3) as the answer is known to be positive by 3 other answers.

Comment: Concerning (3): all dense linear orders are back-and-forth equivalent, if that’s what you refer to. In other words, the theory of dense linear orders is complete as a theory in $L_{\infty,\omega}$. The same conclusion in fact holds for any $\omega$-categorical first-order theory in a countable language: since there are only finitely many first-order formulas in $n$ variables nonequivalent over $T$, every $L_{\infty,\omega}$-formula (in finitely many variables) is equivalent to a first-order formula by induction on complexity.

Answer (score 2):

1) Take any nondecreasing continuous function from the reals to the reals that is constant in neighborhoods of rationals, and restrict it to irrationals.  This can be constructed as a uniform limit by starting with f(0)(x) = x, enumerating the rationals as r(i) and for each i, setting f(i+1)(x) to be a sum of f(i)(x) and some piecewise linear function supported in a neighborhood of radius 2^(-i) around r(i).

3) [removed due to being a flawed argument - Scott]

Comment: The finite interval assertion in the last sentence is clearly false, since you can take an infinite subsequence of rationals with nested neighborhoods.  I don't see a way to rescue the argument (but it's more or less moot at this point).

Comment: Indeed why not just edit it out?

Answer (score 1):

(3) Here's how to construct an example. We can assume the segment in question was from 0 to 1 non-inclusively. Also, I will write source numbers in *binary* and target numbers in *base 4*.

Consider first the number 1/2, in binary 0.1000... Let's map it to 0.1[0102010...] — it doesn't matter what's inside [...] as long as it's irrational. Now we decide to map all numbers of the form 0.0... to 0.0... and 0.1... to 0.2... . Clearly, so far we didn't break anything.

Now, let's take a different rational number, e.g. 1/4 = 0.010... Similarly, we decide to map it to one of irrationals of the form 0.01[10011010...] and the segment [1/4, 1/2] is ready to go to 0.02...

Select the next rational number, e.g. 1/3 = 0.0101(01). It's breaking in half the segment destined to go to 0.02... No problem, again we select some irrational 0.021[010012...] for 1/3 and move left and right subsegments to 0.020... and 0.022...

Now, so far I was using xxx0, xxx1 and xxx2. But let's sometimes move segments to xxx1, xxx2 and xxx3. Let's do it whenever I'm on a level which is a square of natural number.

We're still increasing, yahoo!

Repeat this process for all rationals ordered by denominator. For any rational we have selected an irrational number by definition. For any irrational, it's the limit of segments broken down into parts. Each breakdown reveals exactly one digit of the result — so we reconstruct it digit-by-digit in ternary. It has infinite number of digits. Moreover, these digits never become periodical thanks to the fact that each $n^2$-digit was shifted by 1. So the result is irrational too.

Since every two irrationals are separated by rational, this function is always increasing. Qued erat construirum.

Comment: (Sorry for nitpicking on what is not maths, but the right Latin ending phrase would be "Quod erat construendum"  :)  )