# Cardinality of a linear independent subset of a free module over a commutative ring which is not an integral domain

Tags: modules, ac.commutative-algebra

If R is a commutative ring with unity and not an integral domain and F is a free R-module with rank k,is there a linear independent set with cardinality > k?
I prooved that this is not true if R is an integral domain and is true if R is not a commutative ring but i can't see the answer to my question.

Comment: It's true. Do you know german? http://www.matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/article.php?sid=1168

Comment: Alternatively (if $k$ is finite): http://www.mathlinks.ro/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=124137

Comment: I think this is a multi-dupe: see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/30860/ranks-of-free-submodules-of-free-modules/30862#30862 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-2-11

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help.The best 2 answers i found are the one of Robin Chapman in this site and the similar one of Papaioannou in the Atiyah-MacDonald solution manual(http://dangtuanhiep.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/papaioannoua_solutions_to_atiyah.pdf)